# Deleting data from sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

in my flask app I have the following code :

```
def get_db():
    conn =sqlite3.connect(db_path)
    cur =conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Files (name TEXT, 
    year TEXT, subject TEXT, kind TEXT, correction INT, 
    description TEXT, date TEXT)""")
    return cur

def query_db(query, args=(), one=False):
    print args   
    cur = get_db().execute(query, args)
    rv = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    return (rv[0] if rv else None) if one else rv

@app.route('/admin/<year>/<matiere>/<fichier>')
@requires_auth
def delete(year, matiere, fichier):
    query_db("DELETE from Files where name=?",[fichier])
    return 'Deleted'
```

But when I use this code, the data isn’t deleted, and I don’t understand why. Has someone an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing commit conn.commit()

```
def query_db(query, args=(), one=False):
    print args   
    cur = get_db().execute(query, args)
    rv = cur.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    return (rv[0] if rv else None) if one else rv
```